# Как написать следующий SQL запрос?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы first(int id, int num), second(int num), Нужно вывести те id, в список номеров которых входит всё множество номеров из второй таблицы, то есть в первой таблице например есть записи ((1, 1),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,1),(2,2)) а во второй (1,3,4)
значит результатом запроса должен стать id 1 так как у него есть числа 1,3,4 а номер 2 не подходит, так как совпадение есть только по первому числу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT first.id
FROM first
JOIN second ON first.num = second.num
GROUP BY first.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT first.num) = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT num)
                                     FROM second )
```

Если какое-то из `num` в структуре таблицы определено как UNIQUE, то для соответствующего поля DISTINCT можно убрать.